# Как создать проверку на существование записи?

Tags: python, sqlite

проверять нужно в базе данных `user_id`, `product_id`, `voice` если они совпадают со значениями в переменой, тогда не будем добавлять, а если не совпадает лишь значения `voice` тогда перезаписать его

```
def add_rating(user_id, product_id, voice):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO User (user_id, product_id, voice) VALUES("+ user_id +","+product_id+", "+voice+")")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: если значение в столбцах  `user_id` и `product_id` уже такие существую, то нужно лишь обновить `voice`

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634984/insert-if-not-exists-else-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы обновить значение `voice`, относящееся к заданной паре `(user_id, product_id)` или добавить новую запись, если подобной пары ещё нет в таблице, можно использовать `INSERT OR REPLACE` как показано [в ответе @gaspard, к похожему вопросу INSERT IF NOT EXISTS ELSE UPDATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4815409/4279) В случае конфликта, если запись с парой `user_id`, `product_id` уже существует, то она будет удалена и вставка происходит в любом случае (поэтому, *если запись уже существует, то поля, неуказанные в запросе, могут быть заменены на значение по умолчанию, например, `NULL`*—смотри [описание алгоритма разрешения конфликтов `REPLACE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlite3

c = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c.executescript('''
CREATE TABLE User (user_id INTEGER UNIQUE, product_id INTEGER UNIQUE, voice real);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX voice_idx ON User(user_id, product_id);
''')
c.executemany('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO User VALUES(?,?,?)',
              [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 3), (1, 2, 5)])
print(list(c.execute("SELECT * FROM User")))
```

#### Результат

```
[(2, 3, 3.0), (1, 2, 5.0)]
```

Видно, что первая запись `(1,2,3)` была автоматически удалена и замещена записью `(1,2,5)`.

---

В случае, если в таблице есть другие поля, значения которых хочется сохранить, то можно использовать подход из [ответа @Chris Stavropoulos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7353236/4279) к вопросу [SQLite - UPSERT *not* INSERT or REPLACE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/418898/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlite3

c = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c.executescript("""
CREATE TABLE User (user_id INTEGER UNIQUE, product_id INTEGER UNIQUE, voice real, name text);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX voice_idx ON User(user_id, product_id);

INSERT INTO User values(1, 2, 3, 'abc');
""")
for values in [(2, 3, 3), (1, 2, 5)]:
    with c:
        cur = c.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO User(user_id, product_id, voice) '
                        'values(?, ?, ?)', values)
        if cur.rowcount == 0:  # already exists
            data = dict(zip("user_id product_id voice".split(), values))
            cur.execute('update User set voice=:voice '
                        'where user_id=:user_id and product_id=:product_id', data)
print(list(c.execute("SELECT * FROM User")))
c.close()
```

#### Результат

```
[(1, 2, 5.0, 'abc'), (2, 3, 3.0, None)]
```

Видно, что значение `name` `'abc'` было сохранено при обновлении `voice` на `5.0`.

---

[UPSERT возможно будет встроен в SQLite, начиная с версии 3.24](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_UPSERT.html)  как `ON CONFLICT` условие в `INSERT` запросе (не тестировано):

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO User VALUES(:user_id, :product_id, :voice)'
          ' ON CONFLICT(user_id, product_id) DO UPDATE SET voice=:voice', 
          dict(user_id=1, product_id=2, voice=8))
```