# как сделать проверку на существование записи в таблице Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

например в переменных `user_id` значения `4001` и `product_id` : `12` и `voice` : `4` нужно проверить существуют ли такая запись с данными в базе, если нет то добавить, а если совпадает лишь `user_id` и `product_id` а `voice` не совпадает, то заменить, обновить строку

```
def add_rating(user_id, product_id, voice):
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO User (user_id, product_id, voice) VALUES("+ user_id +","+product_id+", "+voice+")")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Чем данный вопрос отличается от предыдущего вашего вопроса?
([Как создать проверку на существование записи?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517013/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8))

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как ранее был задан практически такой же вопрос, отличающийся небольшими деталями. Следует уточнить (отредактировать) первоначальный вопрос, а не плодить копии.