# Помогите исправить ошибку в коде (получения и проверка данные с БД)

Tags: python, sqlite

есть переменные `u_id, rec_id , voice` с данными которые нужно записать в БД в таблицю `User`но при условиях что таких данных в таблицы не существует

Таблица `User`:

'`user_id`' , '`recipe_id`' , '`voice`'

```
def add_rating(u_id, rec_id, voice):
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()

##
## выбираем данные из таблицы User и сверяем с переменными u_id , rec_id  
## 

result = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE user_id = "+u_id+" AND recipe_id= "+rec_id+""
num_rows = c.execute(result)

##
## проверяем, если данные совпадают, тогда обновить лишь voice   
##    

if(num_rows==num_rows):
    sql = "UPDATE User (voice), VALUES("+voice+")"
    c.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

##
## если данные не совпадают тогда добавить их  
##

elif(num_rows!=num_rows):
    sql = "INSERT INTO User (user_id, recipe_id, voice) VALUES("+ u_id +", "+rec_id+", "+voice+")"
    c.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Что по-вашему этот код должен делать и что он делает не так?

Comment: ошибка

'c.execute(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error'

Comment: @Surfer у вас ошибка в запросе. `sql = "UPDATE User (voice), VALUES("+voice+")"` - запятая после скобки

Comment: все равно не работает, может я неверно запрос создал

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Как создать проверку на существование записи?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517013/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во избежании SQL-инъекций нельзя запросы создавать с помощью конкатенации строк. Вместо этого необходимо использовать знак `?` там, где необходимо использовать значения. А в качестве второго аргумента метода `execute` необходимо использовать кортеж передаваемых значений. 
[DB-API](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html) 
**То есть получится вот так:**

```
##
## выбираем данные из таблицы User и сверяем с переменными u_id , rec_id  
##

num_rows = c.execute("SELECT * FROM User WHERE user_id =? AND recipe_id=?", (u_id, rec_id))

##
## проверяем, если данные совпадают, тогда обновить лишь voice   
##    

if(num_rows==num_rows):
    c.execute("UPDATE User (voice) VALUES(?)", voice)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

##
## если данные не совпадают тогда добавить их  
##

elif(num_rows!=num_rows):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO User (user_id, recipe_id, voice) VALUES(?,?,?)", (user_id, recipe_id, voice))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: 1- `num_rows==num_rows` проверка бесполезна: `num_rows` это курсор, возвращаемый `c.execute()`—условие всегда `True`. 2- `UPDATE` команда некорректна. 3- Все три sql команды можно [заменить на `INSERT OR REPLACE` или на `INSERT OR IGNORE`+`UPDATE`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/517467/23044).