# Как сделать проверку на уникальность записи перед добавлениям в таблицу?

Tags: python, sqlite

Есть переменные `u_id` и `re_id` с данными.

И есть таблица в базе данных `User` с ветками: `id` , `u_id` и `re_id`.

Необходимо запретить добавления дубликата, - когда данные с переменными `u_id` и `re_id` уже существуют в таблице

```
def add_rating(user_id, recipe_id, voice):
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("INSERT INTO User (u_id, re_id) VALUES("+ u_id +","+re_id+")")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

нужна проверка, не по уникальному id , а по вносимым данным , то есть проверять данные в u_id и re_id таблицы на уникальность

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Как создать проверку на существование записи?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517013/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно создать уникальный индекс для этой таблицы и комбинации полей:

```
c.execute("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX User ON t1(u_id, re_id)");
conn.commit()
```

Comment: а если нужно проверить, добавлена была или нет , и выполнить соответствующую функцию ??

Comment: В случае нарушения уникальности вылетит исключение. Его можно обработать.

Comment: покажите на примере кода

Comment: Примерно так:
```
try:
  c.execute("INSERT INTO User (u_id, re_id) VALUES("+ u_id +","+re_id+")")
  conn.commit()
except sqlite3.Error:
  print('Oblom')
  conn.rolback()
```
За точность имён не ручаюсь - смотри документацию: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: в таблицю все равно попадают одинаковые данные

Comment: это не то что мне нужно

Answer (score 0):

@tonal подсказал правильное решение – оно позволяет поддерживать правильность данных на стороне БД.

Если по какой-то причине нужно перенести эту логику на сторону Питона, можно поступить следующим образом: перед тем, как вставить данные, проверить есть ли они в БД. Для этого можно выполнить запрос вида `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User WHERE u_id=1 AND re_id=2`. Запрос вернёт число строк, удовлетворяющих условию. Если это не ноль – такая строка уже есть в таблице.