# Проверка на дубликат sqlite

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Смотрел здесь: [Как сделать проверку на уникальность записи перед добавлениям в таблицу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517481/), и здесь: [Как создать проверку на существование записи?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517013/) - не помогло.
Есть таблица:

```
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'
                                            'Name TEXT UNIQUE,'
                                            'Value INTEGER) ')
```

Скрипт периодически парсит данные обновляя БД.
Если `name` повторяется, то надо просто перейти к следующей итерации.

```
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO table (Name, Value)  VALUES(?, ?)', (Name, Value))
```

Получаю ошибку:

> sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: table.Name

Была идея просто обрабатывать ошибку, но есть ли способ это сделать с помощью SQL?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517481/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83

Comment: Там предлагается обработать ошибку с помощью try except. Возможно ли это с делать с помощью запросов sql?

Comment: посмотрите последний ответ в указанном посте

Comment: Спасибо, не правильно понял его ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `ON CONFLICT IGNORE`.

Пример:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab(
   ...>   Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   ...>   Name TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE,
   ...>   Value INTEGER);
sqlite>
sqlite> INSERT INTO  tab(Name, Value) VALUES("111", 111);
sqlite> INSERT INTO  tab(Name, Value) VALUES("111", 111);
sqlite> INSERT INTO  tab(Name, Value) VALUES("111", 222);
sqlite> INSERT INTO  tab(Name, Value) VALUES("222", 222);
sqlite> INSERT INTO  tab(Name, Value) VALUES("222", 333);
sqlite>
sqlite> select * from tab;
Id          Name        Value
----------  ----------  ----------
1           111         111
4           222         222
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, избавили от лишнего кода