# Как сделать запрет на повтор?

Tags: sqlite

Проблема такая, если занесли запись через запрос 'INSERT INTO' в таблицу, и второй раз допустим случайно с таким же названиям, то данные не добавляются и это хорошо, НО сам 'id' увеличивается в значении, каждой раз на одиницю, если совпадают названия , что в моем случаи мне не подходит , возможно ли как-то это решить ?

#### Параметры таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE "content" (
"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
"title" TEXT NOT NULL, 
"category" INTEGER NOT NULL,
"directians" TEXT NOT NULL,
"time" INTEGER,
"img" TEXT,
"autor" TEXT,
"datetime" DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
UNIQUE ("title") ON CONFLICT REPLACE)
```

Comment: А если попробовать insert ... on duplicate key update хз будет он увеличивать id или нет, может и не будет ...

Comment: id, как суррогатный уникальный ключ, не предназначен для того чтобы иметь какое-либо осмысленное значение. Его задача быть уникальным и простым. Пусть себе увеличивается вам-то что? Потратите много усилий на решение надуманной проблемы, а толку от этого абсолютно никакого.

Comment: @Mike 1. Будет. 2. Это не составляет ни малейшей проблемы.

Comment: попробовали вы `UPSERT` пример из моего ответа на ваш вопрос [Как создать проверку на существование записи?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517013/23044). Чем его результаты отличаются от желаемых?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Если значение ID увеличивается на единицу, то значит что данные, на самом деле, **добавляются**, а если быть точнее, то вновь добавляемые данные **заменяют** предыдущие значения. Об этом поведении говорит строка: `UNIQUE ("title") ON CONFLICT REPLACE`

А для того, чтобы запретить добавление одинаковых данных и соответственно увеличения ID на единицу, нужно просто заменить поведение при конфликтных случаях с этого:

```
UNIQUE ("title") ON CONFLICT REPLACE
```

на вот это:

```
UNIQUE ("title") ON CONFLICT IGNORE
```

Таким образом, вновь добавляемые данные будут игнорироваться и добавление не сработает.

Comment: отлично) а если нужно обновить - перезаписать старую запись на новою ?

Comment: @Surfer обновить = update.

Comment: то есть, вот так `ON CONFLICT UPDATE`  ?

Comment: @Surfer нет, просто вместо добавления новой записи `insert into content(title, category) values("name", "category")` обновлять соответствующие поля у текущей с помощью `update content set title = "name", category = "category" where id = 3`

Comment: это я знаю) вы не совсем поняли, добавить если нет такой записи , а обновить если уже есть

Comment: @Surfer это уже новый вопрос, оформляйте, подумаем.

Answer (score 3):

На php

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM content WHERE title=?");
$sth->execute(array($title));
$result = $sth->fetchColumn();
if ($result) {
     $db->prepare("UPDATE ...");
} else {
     $db->prepare("INSERT ...");
}
```

На mysql

```
CREATE TABLE content (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
UNIQUE (title));

INSERT INTO content (title) VALUES ('1st Street');

INSERT INTO test.Content (title) VALUES ('1st Street') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title='2st Street';
```

Индекс не меняется, проверял лично на MySql.

Comment: php-решение не выдержит проверки многопоточностью.

Comment: В вопросе всё-таки речь об sqlite.

Answer (score 2):

Причина увеличения Id банальна, в схеме таблицы которую вы привели задекларировано поведение при возникновении конфликта обновлять запись, то есть добавить новую и удалить старую. От этого и возникает изменение Id записи. Нужно изменить ограничение "title" поля таблицы. В зависимости от поведения которое вы хотите получить нужно либо откатывать всю транзакцию или только конфликтующую инструкцию и уже потом обрабатывать в коде исключение ([ссылка на документацию](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)):

```
UNIQUE ("title") ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK
```

или

```
UNIQUE ("title") ON CONFLICT ABORT
```

"ON CONFLICT ABORT" - это поведение по умолчанию в sqlite
Полное описание структуры таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE "content" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "title" TEXT NOT NULL, 
    "category" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "directians" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "time" INTEGER,
    "img" TEXT,
    "autor" TEXT,
    "datetime" DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UNIQUE ("title") ON CONFLICT ABORT)
```

Если это тот случай когда нельзя изменить схему таблицы (хотя наврядли), то нужно перенести проверку существования уникального "title" в код, но это несёт свои риски в многопоточной записи в таблицу.

Answer (score 1):

Хм... Может быть реализовывать по банальному по типу аналогии простых cms движков.
Проверять на существования запись по title
При создании записи, возвращать созданный автоинкремент (IDENT_CURRENT, LAST_INSERT_ID) и при следующих запросах обновлять запись или зная что авто инкремент мы получили сообщить о том что запись существует.

Также можно сделать защиту на стороне клиента от повторных случайных нажатий с помощью javascript. Сделав кнопку не активной в течении N секунд.

Answer (score 0):

Не сильно знаком с SQLite, но вот что удалось нагуглить:

Можно попробовать контролировать автоинкремент самостоятельно,
например, через COALESCE вот так:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "content" 
        (id, title, category, directians, time, img, autor, datetime)
    VALUES(
        COALESCE(
            SELECT id FROM "content" WHERE title={title}, --если такой id существует оставляем его
            SELECT last_insert_rowid() FROM "content" -- если нет, вставляем по автоинкременту
        ),
        {title}, 
        {category}, 
        {directians}, 
        {time}, 
        {img}, 
        {autor}, 
        {datetime}
    )
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace/4330694#4330694)

Answer (score -2):

Правильно сделать - это оставить как есть т.е если id - увеличивается когда даже запрос не прошел -это нормально, если вам нужен порядковый номер то вы можете добавить дополнительное поле для этого, или если при выводе нужно нумеровать записи...то сортируете по id а номер пишите просто порядковый номер строки из выборки - так правильней.

Но, если вам нужно по какимто из своих соображений именно так , то решение следующее:

```
INSERT INTO CONTENT (id, title) SELECT max(id) + 1, 'your value' from content
```

Comment: Интересно а чего минусют то?....есть варианты получше?..предложите...

Comment: Запустите одновременно десять запросов. Все десять получат один и тот же id. Девять из десяти завершаться ошибкой. Проверьте. Если это так, то поставьте себе минус сами и за меня. (я не ставил)

Comment: Вариант получше - не исполнять рабски желания заказчика, пытаясь родить телегу на кривых колесах, а оставить только первый обзац.

Comment: Если не исполнять рабские желания заказчика - то в 99% компаний ваш пошлют искать работу дальше......потому что заказчик хочет так как он хочет...и у него свои аргументы.....советы советами...но делать нужно так как хочет заказчик...

Comment: > Запустите одновременно десять запросов.  - вообщето ответ был в том что так лучше не делать,  а код приведен для примера как можно сделать (если всеже заказчику нужно сделать так - как лучше не делать)