# Как перезаписать значения в строке без увеличения id?

Tags: python, sqlite

Как перезаписать значения в строке без увеличения id?

Comment: этот вопрос (в разных вариациях) уже многократно задавался. Вот [вопрос с двумя различными решениями в моём ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517013/23044). К каким нежелательным результатам второй показанный способ в вашем случае приводит?

Comment: *"не работает"* не информативно. Какие конкретно результаты вы ожидали и что вместо этого получаете. Создайте полный минимальный пример как в ответе (пример в ответе естественно работает как написано). Иначе говоря создайте [mcve].

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: это вы *первый* пример из ответа попробовали. Я же явно писал, что в этом случае следует *второй* (UPSERT) пример пробовать.

Comment: невнимательный :) а что такое `UNIQUE INDEX` и зачем он нужен?

Comment: если я напишу просто `UNIQUE ("title")` при созданные таблицы ?

Comment: Не помещайте решение в ваш вопрос. Вместо этого опубликуйте его как ответ. Индекс полезен, чтобы запрос `where user_id=:user_id and product_id=:product_id` эффективен был (чтобы не нужно было всю таблицу сканировать) и возможно, чтобы `INSERT OR IGNORE` правильно работало (попробуйте с индексом и без, а уже не помню всех деталей).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sqlite3

category = 1
directians = "Описания"
time = 45
img = 'http://..'
author = 'author'
title = 'terror'

c = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c.executescript("""
CREATE TABLE content(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,title TEXT NOT NULL, category INTEGER NOT NULL, directians TEXT NOT NULL,time INTEGER,img TEXT,author TEXT, datetime DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX title_x ON content(title);

INSERT INTO content(title,category,directians,time,img,author) values('terror',31,'Описания','33','http://','author');
INSERT INTO content(title,category,directians,time,img,author) values('terror2',32,'Описания','33','http://','author')
""")
for values in [(title,category,directians,time,img,author)]:
    with c:
        cur = c.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO content(title,category,directians,time,img,author) '
                        'values(?,?,?,?,?,?)', values)
        if cur.rowcount == 0:  # already exists
            data = dict(zip("title category directians time img author".split(), values))
            cur.execute('update content set title=:title, category=:category,directians=:directians,time=:time,img=:img,author=:author '
                        'where title=:title', data)
            print("БД: Данные были заменены!")
        else:
            print("БД: Новые данные добавлены.")
```