# Не получается создать верное условие

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, вконтакте

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/Scream03/mysite/db.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(user_id))
rows = cursor.fetchall()

    elif text[0].lower() == 'баланс':
        for row in rows:
            if row[0] != user_id:
                cursor.execute(
                    "INSERT INTO users VALUES ({}, 2500, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)".format(user_id))
                conn.commit()
                conn.close()
                api.messages.send(access_token=token, peer_id=peer_id,
                                  message=head + ',\n\n |» Баланс: 2500$' + footer)
            else:
                api.messages.send(access_token=token, peer_id=peer_id,
                                  message=head + ',\n\n |» Баланс: ' + row[1] + '$' + footer)
```

Нужно записывать user_id, если его нет в базе данных, условие `if row[0] != user_id:`
не работает

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как создать проверку на существование записи?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517013/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Если записи с требуемым id нет, до условия дело просто не дойдет. Нужно проверять сам рекордсет.

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
if not rows:
    print('no record with id')
else:
    print('record exists')
```