# Как проверить существует ли значение в SQLite ANDROID?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Я создал таблицу Android Studio. Создал запись имя Петя id 1. Но я могу создать еще одну запись Петя с id 2. Как ограничить создание записи в таблицу, если параметр name уже существует?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как создать проверку на существование записи?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517013/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8)

Comment: Написал, что мне надо Android Studio. Java, а там python

Comment: там речь про sqlite, к программе же android studio и интерпретаторам java/python/и.т.д. никакого отношения ваш вопрос не имеет.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707796/sqlitedatabase-insert-only-if-the-value-does-not-exist-not-via-raw-sql-command